# Perform a function till mouse is pressed down

Tags: c#, mouseevent, mousedown

I want to how to implement this

Till i press the mouse button down i want some code to execute. The problem is I used mouse Down event but it works like a mouse click event.
Can you please help.

Comment: use `MouseDown` event to start your code, and then use `MouseUp` event to stop it.

Comment: `MouseDown` is only called once. I think you're thinking that it is called repeatedly while the mouse is held down, but this is not the case.
`MouseClick` is called after a mouse is pressed down *and* subsequently released.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 functions, one to start your code to execute, and one to stop it.

Call the start on a `mouseDown` event, and call the stop on `mouseUp`.

Unless I don't understand what you're trying to do, that should be the way to go.